# Como hacer que se ejecute un caso aleatorio en switch fácilmente

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo hacer que se ejecute un caso aleatorio en switch usando alguna probabilidad matemática?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empezamos creando `function randNum(min, max)` que devolvera un número aleatorio entre el valor de `min` y el de `max`.
Con `var variableNum = Math.ceil(randNum(1,9));` Asignamos un número aleatorio a la variable `variableNum`, Redondeamos este número hacía arriba y a un solo dígito para trabajar más fácilmente.

Y acontinuación evaluamos `variableNum` con `switch()` y establecemos los posibles casos.

```js
function randNum(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
var variableNum = Math.ceil(randNum(1,9));
switch(variableNum){
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
    var possibility = "posibilidad 1";
    break;
  case 4:
  case 5:
  case 6:
    var possibility = "posibilidad 2";
    break;
  case 7:
  case 8:
  case 9:
    var possibility = "posibilidad 3";
    break;
}

console.log(possibility);
```

En este ejemplo `variableNum` será un float entre 1 y 9 que luego se redondea hacia arriba para para asegurar que puedan cumplirse todos los casos.
finalmente, según el valor de `variableNum`, se ejecuta la instrucción que en este caso es crear y asignarle una cadena a la variable`possibility`.

Comment: Excelente , estaría bueno para implementarlo en un juego de azar.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte... las preguntas autorespondidas de este estilo deberian aportar un poco mas que lo que dice la documentacion de la funcion... esto que contas esta [aca](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: deberías explicar por que los `case` van juntos y las ventajas de esa sintaxis.